# show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k\cdot 1^{n-k}= 3^n$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Show that  $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k\cdot 1^{n-k}= 3^n$$

I know this true but i really having a hard time arrive there.
Is it just that $(2+1)^n = 3^n$?

Comment: Yes. It is literally just that $(2+1)^n=3^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed, you are just writing the binomial expansion of $(2+1)^n$.

Comment: i felt like it was to simple